# Migrating a PHP interspire ecommerce shop

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, interspire-shopping-cart

I am looking to migrate an interspire ecommerce shop from one server to another. I have successfully transferred all files from one to other via SFTP and moved the shop database over too. I have edited the config.php file to update the MySQL logins but the shop doesn't load, just a white screen.

I'm not sure where to go from here, any advice would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm running an Ubuntu (14.04) LAMP stack

Comment: Did you check your error logs?

Comment: Standard debugging stuff should nail it in a few minutes : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death